# Detecting when Firefox is showing a Server not found message

Tags: firefox, kiosk

I'm using [Firefox for a digital signage](http://webconverger.com) application, and there a couple of scenarios where a **Server not found** might result.

- Network outage on boot
- DNS fails to resolve for the homepage
- Server (its homepage) fails to respond
- Boots and the network just isn't ready by the time Firefox is loaded
- Browser crashes, [process is restarted](https://github.com/Webconverger/base/blob/master/home/webc/pb.sh), but the network is down

In such cases I would like to detect this state and simply kill and restart the process after a minute. Any other tweaks or suggestions, I'm all ears.

You do not need to consider the case whereby the loaded Web application loses Internet connectivity. That scenario I think has been handled by the Web app itself, once it has loaded.

I don't want to go down the local httpd or local extension/addon route.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered a simple solution of overriding Firefox **netError.xhtml** to do a simple `location.reload` every ten seconds.

Source code can be found from https://github.com/Webconverger/iceweasel-webconverger/blob/master/content/netError.xhtml#L410